# In .NET MAUI, how do I set the font-weight of a label?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I cannot find the property of settings weight for a font.

"FontAttributes" exists, but only have italic, bold, and none. Is there a way to set font-weight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it is not exactly answer, but what I do is use different font family.

Usually in Styles.xaml, using a Setter.

I have different files, in Resources/Fonts.
(SemiBold, Bold, Regular etc..)

Comment: Thank you, I will try to see if this works. It sounds like it might be my problem, I only have two fonts "installed" in the project.

Comment: @eengstroem it will work. They need to be in Resources/Fonts folder. Example file names: "Roboto-Bold.ttf", "Roboto-Regular.ttf". when you right click and see properties, the Build Action should be: "MauiFont". If something does not work, write here again. We will make it working.